# Overheating in Jessie

Tags: debian, fan

I just upgraded to Jessie and my laptop, a vostro 1710, is overheating.

```
alexis1@debian:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +62.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +61.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +97.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +115.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +115.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

i8k-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Right Fan:      0 RPM
CPU:          +72.0°C  
temp2:        +87.0°C
```

I tried to follow what is indicated here :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working

Apparently the BIOS is overriding fan control by i8kutils. The solution exposed is what I have followed :

1. Getting the source ff i8kutils to get "smm"

   $ sudo apt-get build-dep i8kutils
   $ apt-get source i8kutils
2. extract the archive

   $ tar xvf i8kutils_1.41.tar.xz
       $ cd i8kutils-1.41/

I am on a 32-bits system so after

```
$gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I. -o smm smm.c
```

then

```
$sudo ./smm 30a3
```

returns

```
eax=000030a3 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000 0
```

Finally when I type

```
i8kfan 2 2
```

I get

```
-1 2
```

i.e. my fans start and then suddenly stop !

What should I do ?
Thanks !

Comment: I tried what is there

http://www.linux-hell.com/2015/04/11/temperature-control-on-dell-latitude-e7440-under-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts/

It seems to work, apart from the fact that when I run

i8kmon -a

the van goes on and off every second, and my computer freezes. I need to stop the daemon to come back to normal.

Comment: One side question: which frequency scheduler do you use for your CPU? Did you try using the Nvidia proprietary driver instead of Nouveau to see if the GPU temperature is lower?

Comment: How can I know which frenquency scheduler I use ?
and I remember trying to install the nvidia driver for Debian but never managed... 
The problem is that the whole system is too warm, the 2 cores too. 
Apparently the issue is that when modifying the speed of fan, there is a lag of about 0.5 seconds and we can't get rid of it
source :
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=96356

Comment: I usually install the package `cpufrequtils` and then you can run the command `cpufreq-info` which gives you many information from your CPU. But you can directly check the /sys FS: current scheduler (aka governor) `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`, current frequency `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`, etc. I only have a discreet GPU in my laptop, but its a Dell Latitude E6440 and it is quiet and cool usually. Hence I'm surprised by how hot it seems to run on yours. The only outlier seems your GPU. Your CPU runs a bit hot, but nothing to worry.

Comment: For the GPU, try to install the driver directly from Nvidia web site. I don't like it much, and it usually means that before any kernel upgrade, you would need to first switch back to Nouveau, upgrade the kernel, and then reinstall the Nvidia driver to avoid any glitches (especially when upgrading from Wheezy to Jessie or next, some intermediate updates might not break it)!! <rant>I tend to avoid Nvidia even though their hardware maybe worth it, the driver support on Linux is just a headache IMHO.</rant>

Comment: Ho, and is there a BIOS update from Dell for your laptop? This might help. Perhaps there was some bugs which prevents the current Linux tool to do their jobs...

Comment: It's quite hot ! I booted on Fedora and
'nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +68.0°C  
i8k-virtual-0
Processor Fan: 2900 RPM
CPU:            +53.0°C  
GPU:            +58.0°C  
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +46.0°C 
Core 1:       +43.0°C )'
As I said I've tried with the nvidia driver and as you mentionned it was a pain ! I remember the PC was overheating when I upgraded to wheezy and then got back to normal after playing around with 'sensors' and 'fancontrol'. Might just stick with Fedora
Thanks for your answers anyways, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: And for the BIOS update I think I'd prefer avoid touching it, especially if everything is working fine with Fedora :)

Comment: Hmm I'm also running Fedora on my Dell laptop... Maybe you should **open a bug on Debian bug tracker**. But I had to do a recent BIOS/EFI update as my laptop keyboard was misbehaving, it sometimes got a key stuck and was repeating it infinitely. Very annoying!! But the BIOS update fixed it. Anyway, I did it because it was not working. If everything work, it is not mandatory.